# Resources->Current project triggers is gone from Apps Script code editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I used Resources->current project triggers to control when certain projects would execute. For example some of my projects would update a spreadsheet every day in the morning around 4am. Now when I click Resources, the current project triggers option is gone. What happened? This change was made in the last day or so, because last time I was working on a project it was there. Now its gone.

Comment: Please confirm "Edit" on your script editor. They have been moved from "Resources" to "Edit" . The triggers which have already been set are running.

Comment: They've been making small changes to the editor for the last few weeks.

Answer (score 7):

"Current project's triggers" and "All your triggers" are now under the "Edit" menu at the bottom of the list.   The two menu items for triggers have been removed from the "Resources" menu and moved to the "Edit" menu in the Apps Script code editor.﻿