# Google sheet Tools Editor menu Resources incomplete

Tags: google-apps-script, resources, editor

Since yesterday the menu "Resources" in the editor of google sheets  only the items "Library" and "Advanced Google Services" shows up. So the items "Current Project's Triggers"as "All Triggers" are not visible anymore.
The installed triggers are still working, but cannot change them and cannot add new triggres anymore.

Comment: Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663478/resources-current-project-triggers-is-gone

Answer (score 2):

The items "Current Project's Triggers" and "All Triggers" have been moved to the "Edit" menu of your Script editor.

Comment: Thanks Anton! Is this not announced by Google?

Comment: I see nothing in the release notes, so I guess they considered it too small a change to be worth announcing.

Comment: Also Stack Overflow is not the place to ask such questions